# Unable to override .NET abstract class in CLR/C++

Tags: clr

I have
logger.cs:

```
public abstract class LogProvider
{
    protected abstract void DoLog(LogEvent logEvent);
}
```

my_code.cpp

```
ref class DebugLogProvider : public LogProvider
{
public:

    virtual void DoLog(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(gcnew System::String("fsdfsdf")); 
    }
};
```

I got error:

```
error C2259: '`anonymous-namespace'::DebugLogProvider': cannot instantiate abstract class
message : 'void LogProvider::DoLog(LogEvent ^)': is abstract
```

How to override DoLog ?

Comment: Use the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `LogProvider` class has a pure virtual function `DoLog()` that is declared as abstract without an implementation. Any derived class that inherits from `LogProvider` must implement `DoLog()`.

In your `DebugLogProvider` class, you need to implement the `DoLog()` function to override the pure virtual function in the base class. e.g:

```
ref class DebugLogProvider : public LogProvider
{
public:
    virtual void DoLog(LogEvent^ logEvent) override
    {
        Console::WriteLine(gcnew System::String("fsdfsdf")); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Ahhh Thanks! I haven't added ^ after type LogEvent in function definition. That is why it treated it as value but not ref. So signature of the function is different to what is defined in base class.